# How to create very large ones matrix in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Suppose you want to create an `n*n` matrix with all ones. This could easily be done by `np.ones`. However, if `n` is in million-level, it may take too much memory. Is there any alternative to do so?

Comment: Storing large amounts of data takes a lot of space. There is no way to change this. But maybe you can provide as with some information about your use case, then we might be able to provide you with an idea.

Comment: Do you need to modify the matrix in any way? If not: `np.broadcast_to(1, (1_000_000, 1_000_000))`. Takes 112 bytes on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: no

The long answer: it depends on what you want to do with that matrix.

If you want to store Boolean values for instance, you can pass `np.uint8`as the `dtype`argument and reduce the memory usage to one fourth. You can also use a [sparse matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html), where you only store the indices of your non-one values and just assume everything else to be ones. I'm not sure if the scipy version works with an all ones matrix or only all zero matrices.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the fn.py framework. It supports infinite sequence decelerations. 
Check out https://github.com/kachayev/fn.py for an example.